# How to add weekday to DateInput widget

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form with a `DateField`

```
class AddMeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    meeting_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'id':'select-date'}), 
        input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y',), 
        initial=date.today)

    class Meta:
            model = Meeting
            fields = '__all__'
```

I have added a `DateInput` widget to format to UK date standards: `dd/mm/yyy`, but how can I add a weekday so it yields `Sun 02/08/2015`?

I don't see an option in the docs ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%a` for the abbreviated weekday (see the Python [strftime and strptime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for a full list).

```
class F(forms.Form):
    meeting_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%a %d/%m/%Y', 
                               attrs={'id':'select-date'}),
        input_formats=('%a %d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%Y',),
        initial=date.today)
```

Note that I've left `"%d/%m/%Y"` in `input_formats` so that the form will still accept inputs without the weekday. You can remove it if you prefer.